# Recover deleted column from Sharepoint 2013 list

Tags: sharepoint-2013

Deleted a column(with data) from Sharepoint 2013 list by mistake. There is no backup saved. Is there a way to recover this list with all the data intact?

Answer (score 0):

No. Deleted columns do not go to the Recycle bins, and with no back up, the data is lost. Are you sure there is no SQL backup of the SharePoint farm available?